# Dagger 2 & Serialization

Tags: android, serialization, persistence, dagger-2

My Activity, lets call it `MainActivity`, has a class it relies on, lets call it `LogicClass`. This class has a state - and that state should be **persisted**.

To clarify, a general flow would look something like this.

- `MainActivity` is freshly created.
- `LogicClass` is created with the **default** state.
- Some actions are performed and `LogicClass`'s state changes.
- `MainActivity` is stopped / destroyed and thusly so is `LogicClass`.
- `MainActivity` is recreated
- `LogicClass` is created with the **changed** state.

Before using dependency injection, what used to happen was `LogicClass` implemented `Serializable` and `MainActivity` created a `LogicClass` instance. `MainActivity` was responsible to serialize it when the activity stopped and deserialize it when the activity was created.

Before:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LogicClass mLogicClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ..

        mLogicClass = deserializeLogic();
        if (mLogicClass == null) {
            mLogicClass = new LogicClass();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // ..

        serializeLogic()
    }
}
```

Now I'm using Dagger2 for DI, so things look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject LogicClass mLogicClass;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ..

        injectDependencies();

    }
}
```

What is the correct approach for serialization using Dagger 2?

The first things that came to mind was to make `LogicClass` able to serialize and deserialize its state via a serialization utility, creating `load()` and `save()` methods, the former being called by the constructor, and the latter being called from outside - in my case, by `MainActivity` in the `onStop()` method. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could move the deserialization code into the `@Module` that creates `LogicClass`, assuming that you have one, or create one for it. The problem with that is that Dagger 2 components don't do any cleanup when they go away do you'd still have to have the serialization code triggered by the `MainActivity`.

Alternatively, you could run the deserialization code after creating the default state, overriding the `mLogicClass` field if it could find its serialized form.

If `LogicClass` is too expensive to create twice (once for the default state that is simply discarded when replaced by the deserialized instance) then you will need to stop injecting the field and simply request it from the component, e.g. by adding a `LogicClass logicClass()` method to the component. That way you could still create the default state only if deserialization didn't find the serialized form.